# Division in base N

Tags: c, radix, integer-division, base-conversion

I was wondering if there was a specific algorithm for doing this in C.
I came up with some approaches however.

The problem: I have 2 numbers in base 7. The numbers are divisible, so my answer will always be an integer. I wish to calculate the quotient.

The easiest way could be perhaps to convert both numbers I have in base 10 from base 7, then divide normally using / operator and then reconvert the answer back to base 7.

This method has a lot of drawbacks, excessive time consumption, and majorly, overflow. If the length of the divident exceeds approx (17-19), the number when converted to base 10 won't fit in a long long int.

After seeing quite a bit, an easy method to do the above is by repeated multiplication. 
Example 202 and 13
I could repeatedly add 13 in base 7, to reach till a number of times that it has to be added to get 202. and this would be the answer. However I am unable to think on how I could multiply these.

What am I asking help with?: An algorithm/pseudocode  or code(C/C++, as that is the only language I know) for the division of two numbers, and getting a quotient in base 7. The result would be a perfect integer.

### Thank you so much.

```
#define max 2000

long long int bconvert(long long int x) //conversion from base 7 to decimal
{   long long int i=0,ans=0;
    while(x>0)
    {
    ans+=(x%10)*pow(7,i);
    x/=10;
    i++;
}
return ans;
}

 int main() {
long long int A,B,L,a,b,c,C,arr[max],i,j,k,arr1[max],r;
    scanf("%lld %lld %lld",&A,&B)
    a=bconvert(A);
    b=bconvert(B);
    c=a/b; //decimal division
    k=0;
    C=0;
    while(c>0)
    {
        r=c%7;
        c/=7;
        C+=r*pow(10,k);
        k++;
    }
    cout<<C<<endl;
```

Output is the quotient in base 7, same form as input.

Comment: There's actually a faster method than just direct repeated multiplication used back in the days of mechanical calculators, similar to long division. As far as actual addition/multiplication, you could just have an array of digits and work with one digit column at a time.

Comment: Computer arithmetic is usually done in binary (occasionally BCD). Other number bases are used for textual representations.

Comment: I understand that, I was wondering if there is any algorithm for the long division bit? I could store my numbers in 2 arrays, their digits. Then add them column by column. This would have to be repeated so many times till I get the resultant divident by repeated addition. The complexity of this would be pretty high I think, assuming I have a large length of A/B.

Comment: How are your base 7 numbers being represented?

Comment: The base 7 numbers, will be received as integers. Like 202, 13, etc. I'll put them via scanf and store them as long long ints.

Comment: Since scanf is so slow, it's best to convert your input to regular integer when as soon as you obtain the data from scanf.

Comment: Yes, but that will cause an overflow. The numbers I am dividing, have a very large length that will exceed the range of long long int. If I could solve it with direct conversion, there would be no point of this question.

Comment: @someone1 you say you have a very large dividend, but what is the maximum value (say in decimal) of the divisor?

Comment: My dividend can have length (in integer form) of around 10^3-6 around that.
The divisor, can be upto say, 10^4-5. 

I'm trying to think of a solution for a smaller case though, like the length of integer form of the number is about 20 digits (approx when it just overflows) (the dividend), so obviously the divisor will have length around (<20) for this case.

Comment: I meant the *divisor*. Would it fit 32-bit `unsigned int`?

Comment: Say I have, A=B*C (A and B are given as inputs, in BASE 7)
Then length of A is a positive integer (not more than 20), I'm trying to solve it for the case just above the overflow.

Comment: As far as I know, a long long int, can store upto 2^64 -1.
Assuming I have a special case, (dividend length 20, and C=1), so my divisor also has length 20. In this case, when I convert this to decimal (It will have the highest term say 9*7^19+....) so this will also overflow, as this sum CAN exceed 2^64-1

Comment: 7^22 is still less than 2^64.

Comment: Yeah, that will work for around that, now if I had a higher length, say above 1000 or so? I did think of storing each digit in an array (size same as max length), then maybe use Karatsuba(modified, to multiply within base 7) or use FFT(Just read something about this, have no idea about it).

Comment: I think you should first get it working, and only then worry about whether or not it is fast enough.

Comment: I have added the code I have written, which is giving some correct and some incorrect answers, any help on what could be wrong?

Comment: Anyone at all? I changed it all to unsigned, but I still get wrong answer for most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can just implement the [long division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division) working directly on the input strings.

Another option is converting the numbers to arbitrary precision integers in base 16807 (7**5), doing the division in that base and converting back the result to base 7.

Comment: I can convert the integers I receive into strings of the digits, however, I'm having a lot of difficulty in writing a long division code for base 7.

As for the conversion, I don't know how to do those conversions, but besides that, wouldn't that take excessive time, and also have a chance of overflow, if the string representation of the number has length of the order ~25

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no time to post complete code (will do so much later today), but following is at least a good outline of "string" division.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Assume no illegal characters
char *strdivide(char *quotient, const char *dividend, const char *divisor, 
    unsigned base) {
  // consume leading zeros
  while (*dividend == '0' && dividend[1]) dividend++;
  while (*divisor == '0' && divisor[1]) divisor++;
  // Detect /0
  if (strcmp(divisor, "0")==0) {
    return "Division by 0";
  }
  // Detect dividend obviousl smaller than divisor
  size_t dd_size = strlen(dividend);
  size_t dv_size = strlen(divisor);
  if (dd_size < dv_size) {
    return strcpy(quotient, "0");
  }

  // Work with copy of dividend
  char div[dd_size + 1];
  memcpy(div, dividend, dd_size + 1);

  // Form quotient
  size_t places = dd_size - dv_size;
  for (size_t i = 0; i<=places; i++) {
    // Assume ASCII
    int digit = 0;
    while (strcmp(div, divisor) >= 0)) {
      int borrow = 0;
      for (unsigned j = dv_size; j-- > 0; ) {
        int diff = value(div[j]) - value(divisor[j]) - borrow;
        if (diff < 0) {
          diff += base;
          borrow = 1;
        } else {
          borrow = 0;
        }
        div[j] = unvalue(diff);
      }
    }
    quotient[i] = unvlaue(digit); // int to char
  }
  quotient[i] = '\0';
  // Check for leading 0 in `quotient[]`, shift if needed.
  return quotient;
}
```

Comment: I have added my own code, however, it's giving the wrong answer for some cases, and correct for a few. Any chance that could be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I asking help with?: An algorithm/pseudocode or code(C/C++, as
>   that is the only language I know) for the division of two numbers, and
>   getting a quotient in base 7.

Leave the meander of interpreting numbers in base 7 as numbers in base 10. Instead, convert the numbers according to their true base on input and output; it's straightforward then.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long long scanbase7()
{
    char str[24];
    return scanf("%23s", str) > 0 ? strtoll(str, NULL, 7) : -1;
}

void printbase7(long long n)
{
    long long p = 1;
    while (n/p > 7) p *= 7;
    do putchar('0'+n/p), n %= p; while (p /= 7);
    puts("");
}

int main()
{
    long long a, b, c;
    a = scanbase7();
    b = scanbase7();
    c = a/b;
    printbase7(c);
}
```